# Different ways of calling class functions

Tags: python

Say I have this code:

```
class ClassStyleA(object):
    def FunctionA(self):
        print "This is Style A."

class ClassStyleB(object):
    def FunctionA(self):
        print "This is Style B."

class InstanceStyleA(ClassStyleA):
    def FunctionB(self):
        print "This is also Style A."

InstanceStyleB = ClassStyleB()
```

If I want to call, for example, `FunctionA`, from `InstanceStyleA`, I need to type it like this:

```
InstanceStyleA().FunctionA()
```

If I want to call `FunctionA` from `InstanceStyleB`, I need to type it like this:

```
InstanceStyleB.FunctionA()
```

I need to add a set of parentheses after `InstanceStyleA` in order to call one of its functions, otherwise I get this error:

```
TypeError: unbound method FunctionA() must be called with InstanceStyleA instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Similarly, if I try to add the parentheses after `InstanceStyleB` when calling one of it's functions, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'ClassStyleB' object is not callable
```

Why is this the case? Why are they treated differently if they are both instances of a class?

Comment: For the `NameError` it looks like you have a typo.

Comment: You seem to be *fundamentally* confused about what classes and objects are. I'd consider looking for a general object-oriented programming tutorial and then going back to see how the concepts apply to Python.

Comment: @Mike You are correct, and I fixed and checked that and I still receive an error, albeit a different one.

Comment: have you heard about `__init__()`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code, you actually have three classes and one object, all confusingly named:

- `ClassStyleA` is a *class*, that inherits from `object`
- `ClassStyleB` is also a *class* that inherits from `object`
- `InstanceStyleA` is **not** an *instance*, it is also a *class*, that inherits from `ClassStyleA`.
- `InstanceStyleB` is **not** a *class*, it's an *instance* of the class `ClassStyleB`

To create an *instance* from a *class*, you call the class. So, `ClassStyleA()`, `ClassStyleB()`, `InstanceStyleA()` are all *instances*. So is `InstanceStyleB` - it's a variable to which you assign the instance created with `ClassStyleB`.

Since `InstanceStyleB` (without parentheses) is already an *instance* (of `ClassStyleB`), and not a *class*, you can't call it. This explains your **second** `TypeError`.

Analogously, you can only call *methods* (functions defined in a class, in your example it's `FunctionA` and `FunctionB`) on an *instance*. This explains your **first** `TypeError`: `InstanceStyleA` (again, without parentheses), is a *class*.

(Pedantic aside: much of above is, technically speaking, utter lies, but for the sake of this discussion it's simpler to pretend Python has a clear separation between classes and instances, and functions and methods.)

Comment: @urschrei Specifically, ["lies-to-children"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). Python's conceptual elegance is wonderful and fascinating, but explaining things using only first principles is cumbersome when you're not supposed to use different words for things that behave differently.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't criticising your approach; it's very responsible.

Answer (score 1):

When you call InstanceStyleA with parenthesis, you are creating an instance of InstanceStyleA... and then calling the member function on that instance.  It is basically shorthand for:

```
obj = InstanceStyleA()
obj.FunctionA()
```

InstanceStyleB is not a class, it is set to an instance of ClassStyleB, so when you are referencing it, there is no need for parenthesis (or instantiating an object).

it would be the same as if you wrote:

```
ClassObject = ClassStyleB()
ClassObject.FunctionA()
```

The **TypeError** is because objects aren't callable.  For instance:

```
d = {} #d is a dictionary
d()    #d used as a function has no meaning
```

I hope this clears up the difference.